# awk with or condition

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with a word Sweden in different variations.

I am trying to get if 34th column has Sweden there

```
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /Sweden/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /sweden/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /SWEDEN/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /^se$/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /^Se$/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /^SE$/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
```

As far as i know it gonna be so slow, as I have 650 million rows.

Is there any way I can get all variation in 1 awk command?

Comment: Since you are processing a CSV-file, please have a look at [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F\" 'tolower($34) ~ /sweden|^se$/' "$ipp" >> sweden.csv
```

Comment: Don't forget, if you are angry, you can use `awk -F\" 'toupper($34) ~ /SWEDEN|^SE$/' "$ipp" >> sweden.csv`

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following `awk` code. Simply making field separator as `"` and in main block checking if field 34th is either containing `sweden`(including upper and lower cases to match any kind of combinations of it) OR it starts from `se`9with both lower and upper case for letters) if any of the condition passes then print that line.

```
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /[Ss][Ww][Ee][Dd][Ee][Nn]|^[Ss][Ee]$/' "$ipp" >> sweden.csv
```

Comment: It would be interesting to measure the performance of between the different approaches. I suspect converting to lowercase would probably be the slowest.

Comment: @P.P, could be, lets see what OP says when OP tests all codes with actual samples, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Case_002dsensitivity), you can use `IGNORECASE` option:

```
awk -F\" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $34 ~ /sweden|^se$/' "$ipp" >> sweden.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be ameloriated as already explained, more generally you might put 6 pattern-action pairs in single `awk` call rather than 6 separate that is

```
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /Sweden/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /sweden/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /SWEDEN/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /^se$/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /^Se$/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /^SE$/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
```

might be written more concisely as

```
awk -F\" '$34 ~ /Sweden/  {print $0}$34 ~ /sweden/  {print $0}$34 ~ /SWEDEN/  {print $0}$34 ~ /^se$/  {print $0}$34 ~ /^Se$/  {print $0}$34 ~ /^SE$/  {print $0}' $ipp >> sweden.csv &
```

Note that if line does contain both `Sweden` and `SWEDEN` it will appear twice (in 6 x `awk` and 1 x `awk` solution) and also order of lines in output might be different between these 2 approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'sub(/^[sS][eE]$|^[Ss]weden$|^SWEDEN$/,$4,$4)' "$ipp" >> sweden.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk '$34~__'                           FS='[\"]'\
>           __="^[Se][Ee]|[Ss][Ww][Ee][Dd][Ee][Nn]|"\
>           "([Kk][Oo][Nn][Uu][Nn][Gg][Aa][Rr][Ii]"  \
>            "[Kk][Ee][Tt] +)?[Ss][Vv][Ee][Rr][Ii][Gg][Ee]" "$ipp" >> sweden.csv
> ```

Between the 2-letter country code and its name in 2 languages this should be at least somewhat comprehensive.